# Fibonacci - Find the sum only of even numbers using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I encountered with this task:

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
```

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

The highest score will be given to solutions using recursion for Fibonacci number calculation."

I know how to calculate the Fibonacci sequence. `return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)`.

And logically to find even numbers sum is to check each time `if (curr%2==0) sum+=curr`

But I don't know how to set the limit of 4000000. This is unclear using recursion. In recursion we need to have initial value which will be decreased and base case where it returns the value.

Could you please explain how to use limit of 4000000 and implement this in recursion?

```
    c={0:0,1:1}
    sum=0;
    def Fib(self,n=5):
        if n in self.c:
            return self.c[n]
        self.c[n]=self.Fib(n-1)+self.Fib(n-2)
        return self.c[n]
```

Python implementation above

Comment: Can you post your recursive function?

Comment: I agree. Please show us the code you got so far.

Comment: You are asking about java. Show us your java code please. We arent here to do your homework.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an interesting, non recursive approach using Streams to lazily generate a sequence of Fibonacci numbers and sum up the even ones under 4 million:

```java
import java.util.stream.*;

class Fib {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum =
            Stream.iterate(new int[]{0, 1},
                           t -> new int[]{t[1], t[0] + t[1]})
            .mapToInt(t -> t[0])
            .filter(n -> n % 2 == 0)
            .takeWhile(n -> n <= 4000000)
            .sum();
        System.out.println("Sum of even fibonacci numbers under 4 million: "
                           + sum);
    }
}
```

Probably not acceptable as a homework answer, but a peek into more advanced ways to approach the problem by breaking it up into a pipeline of individual steps.

A recursive approach (Actual code is left as an exercise for the student): A function that takes the previous two terms of the Fibonacci sequence as arguments (So start with 0 and 1), as well as a third sum argument (Initially 0). Use the previous terms to compute the new number. If it's even, add to the sum. If it's less than 4 million, recurse with new terms and the new sum. If it's greater than, you're done; return the sum.

Answer (score 0):

The limit of 4000000 is independent of the fib function itself. You just need to check if the result of that function is less than 4000000. So maybe something like:

```
int sum = 0;
int i = 1;
int value = fib(i);
while(value < 4000000) {
    if (value % 2 == 0) sum += value;
    i++;
    value = fib(i);
}
//sum contains the answer here
```

There are much more efficient ways to do it, but this should answer it for you

Comment: Your suggested code is *extremely* inefficient but whatever

Comment: @akuzminykh that's what I pointed out myself already. no need to mention that. But for a beginning developer this is the most straightforward and easy to understand way to do it

Comment: Besides, the effiency would mostly depend on the fib function itself. That one could be made efficient with caching for example

Comment: I think, the most beginner-friendly and straightforward example would be just to calculate Fibonacci in a for loop and just to check the other stuff in the same loop. This would also be more efficient.

Comment: @akuzminykh true but OP specifically mentioned recursion needed to be used

Comment: Loops can be "simulated" with recursive functions. :D

Comment: true haha. Anyway, I think it's useful to at least mention this "simple" answer. I believe this is actually the intended answer because it seems to be an exercise of a beginner's course or something. Feel free to disagree. Other people are of course welcome to provide better answers :) And it's up to OP what will help him best.

Comment: @akuzminykh Recursion and loops are the same thing expressed in different ways. (Can the JVM do tail call optimization yet?)

Comment: @Shawn (No, they rely on stack frame information for something.)